# Regex pattern matching

Tags: java, regex

Hello everyone I need a regex to replace everything inside de src= and /> tag on this line

```
src="../../../../../mailPhotos/assasins1.jpeg" alt="" width="284" height="177" /></p>
```

The code I'm trying for the regex is the following:

```
String regex="src=\"../../../../../ndeveloperDocuments/mailPhotos/assasins1.jpeg\" alt=\"\" width=\"284\" height=\"177\" /></p>";
regex=regex.replaceFirst("src./>", "src='cid:"+1001+"'");
```

But it's not replacing anything. What I though is that the regex would do something like "replace everything between src and />", but think I'm wrong as it doesn't work. What would be a regex to use in this case?.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

`.` only matches one character. To match zero or more characters, use `.*` and to match one or more characters use `.+`.

So, your code would be:

```
String regex="src=\"../../../../../ndeveloperDocuments/mailPhotos/assasins1.jpeg\" alt=\"\" width=\"284\" height=\"177\" /></p>";
regex=regex.replaceFirst("src.*/>", "src='cid:"+1001+"'");
```

Comment: Would this regex work on `<src="../../../../../mailPhotos/assasins1.jpeg" alt="/>" width="284" height="177" /></p>`?

Comment: @David: Yeah. It would replace the `="../../../../../mailPhotos/assasins1.jpeg" alt="/>" width="284" height="177" `  part.

Answer (score 0):

A `.` only matches a single character. To match any number of single characters, use `.*` (0 or more) or `.+` (1 or more).

It's easy for this kind of matching to go wrong, however. For example, if you have a string like `src="foo" /> Some other content <br />` your regex will match all the way to the final `/>` and swallow up tyhe other content. A common way to prevent this is to use a regex like `src=[^>]+/>`. The `[^>]` means "any character *except* `>`.